# Crystal reports : record selection greater equals date & time AND less then date & time

Tags: date, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

In crystal reports record selection, how to select records between date and time.

The table has separate fields for date and time.

**For Example:**
From date 24-July-2015  9:00 PM 
To date 25-July-2015  9:00 AM

So i want to select records from 24th July 9:00 PM onwards to 25th July upto 9:00 AM

How can i do this ?

Comment: how is your database field? datetime or only date

Comment: separate field for date and separate field for time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single parameter for both date&time..

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ankur.. But I have a separate field for date and a separate field for time. So how can I do it in record selection. P.S: I am new to crystal reports

Answer (score 0):

Then

1.create a formula to add date & time as single field.. okkk

Formula: datetime(Date,Time)

2.Create a static Parameter type as DateTime and In the value option select the Allow range of value as true..

3.In the Select export choose the formula and parameter that you have created..

[image]

it will work..

**-Ankur**

Comment: Thanks Ankur. Can you elaborate on the 3rd point please? I didnt understand that

Comment: @ankur... don't post multiple answers instead edit your first answer to add the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 solutions..

1. Create a view that combines date and time field of database and create a single column. Use the view in reports and apply a record selection formula for that datetime field like

   `databaseview.datetime>='24-July-2015 9:00 PM' and databaseview.datetime<'25-July-2015 9:00 AM`'
2. Use date in record selection as

   `database.date>='24-July-2015' and database.date<'25-July-2015'`

Now in your report for every field apply a condition on time and display the report.. something like below.

```
If (database.time>='9:00 PM' and database.time<'9:00 AM')
then yourdisplayfield
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to do it. Here is how

in record selection:

```
{@EndDate} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate} and
{@StartDate} in {?FromDate} to {?ToDate} and
(if ({@StartDate} in {?FromDate} to {?FromDate}) then CTime({@StartTime}) >= CTime(ToText({?StartTime})) else if ({@EndDate} in {?ToDate} to {?ToDate}) then CTime({@EndTime}) <= CTime(ToText({?EndTime})) else true)
```

Thanks @Ankur for helping out :)